# Log4j - Have multiple appenders write to the same file with one that always logs

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I have a log4j appender defined like:

```
log4j.logger.com.example = DEBUG, filelog

log4j.appender.filelog=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.filelog.File=c:/app.log
log4j.appender.filelog.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.filelog.layout.ConversionPattern=%d | %m%n
log4j.appender.filelog.DatePattern=.dd-MM-yyyy
```

In my class, I get the logger like:

```
Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());
```

This works properly.  I want to have a logger that always logs certain messages (not errors, but things like how long transactions took).  If I write these at DEBUG or INFO, I won't see them if the log level is changed.  I think I can accomplish this using another appender that writes to the same file.

Is this possible to have two appenders write to the same file?  How would I get the logger instance where I want to use the normal debug appender and the transactional appender in the same class?  These messages won't all be in the same package, so I can't configure a certain package to always log.  Will I have to have these appenders write to different files, or can I retrieve them both in the code and have something like:

```
Log alwaysLogger = LogFactory.getLog(ALWAYS);
alwaysLogger.debug("This message will always be written regardless of the level set on the filelog appender");
```

**Update**
I could write to two different log files if necessary, but how would I get the logger instance in my class?  I don't want to configure one package/class to always use one appender over the other as the classes will have to log information/error messages and the transactional "always" messages during a normal run.  Is there a way to accomplish what I need even if it write to two different log files?

Answer (score 11):

I don't think log4j really supports two appenders writing to the same file because of synchronization issues. Your best bet would be, if possible, to make a switch to [slf4j](http://www.slf4j.org/) using [Logback](http://logback.qos.ch/index.html) as your backend logging system since Logback is log4j's successor and also supports multiple appenders writing to one file. Check out [FileAppender](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#FileAppender) and it's prudent mode.

**Update:** from your description, it seems you should also check out [markers](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#OnMarkerEvaluator). You only need one logger instance, and you can get more fine grained control using markers, because with them you basically say "this log statement has a special purpose, and has to be logged using an appropriate appender". You can also check log appender [additivity](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#overrridingCumulativity), which is usually used when you use two or more appenders for one log statement.

Comment: Ok, even if I need to write to a separate file, how can I get both logger instances in my code?  Do I have to specify which packages will use one appender over the other? I don't want that to happen as these classes will have to log information/error messages as well as the "always" lines.

Comment: This is correct.  It is possible to configure multiple appenders for the same file which will work for a time, but log rotation will result in one of the appenders writting to an old file, and eventually to log messages being lost.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I'm aware, the instantiation of loggers with a package & class identifier is just a convention. You are free to create multiple logger instances in any class and give them any identifier.

```
Log alwaysLogger = LogFactory.getLog("a.b.c.ALWAYS");
Log sometimesLogger = LogFactory.getLog("a.b.c.SOMETIMES");
```

As for writing to the same file, I have not tried it but it should be possible, at least from a single thread. You may need to write your own appender rather than relying on one of the default ones.

Answer (score 2):

I got this to work by using `AsyncAppender`s. I had my main appender which specified a file to log to, and had my other appenders refer to it.

e.g.

```
<appender name="top" class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="file" value="myLog.log" />
</appender>

<appender name="other" class="org.apache.log4j.AsyncAppender">
    <appender-ref ref="top" />
</appender>

<logger name="com.example.MyCLass">
    <appender-ref ref="other" />
</logger>
```

You can add other filters, or whatever to the other appenders. As far as I can tell with my own app, the logs seem to roll, and the appender filters work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can "workaround" to have 2 appenders writing to the same file.

Checkout this [code + example](https://github.com/andresoviedo/java-utilities/tree/master/src/main/java/org/andresoviedo/util/log4j):

Any questions welcome.