# Log4j configuration

Tags: log4j

I have two appenders, file and console, in my project.  I would like to configure my application to perform as such:

all loggers with name "my.app.*":

```
1. log events DEBUG and higher to fileA
2. log events DEBUG and higher to fileB
```

all other loggers:

```
1. log events WARN and higher to fileA
2. log events DEBUG and higher to fileB
```

Ideally, the configuration would look something like this:

```
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">
<appender name="fileA" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender">
    <!-- configuration -->
</appender>

<appender name="fileB" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender">
    <!-- configuration -->
</appender>

<logger name="my.app" additivity="false">
    <level="DEBUG"/>
    <appender-ref ref="fileA"/>
</logger>

<logger name="" additivity="true">
    <level="DEBUG"/>
    <appender-ref ref="fileB"/>
</logger>

<root>
    <level="WARN"/>
    <appender-ref ref="fileA"/>
</root>
</log4j>
```

However, this setup causes loggers named "my.app" to only log to console, and all other loggers to log to console on WARN and above.  Essentially, `<logger name="">` is being ignored.  Is there another way to emulate this behavior with log4j?

PS. I apologize for the poor formatting, really struggling to get this to work tonight :/

Comment: did you forget to type the second appender in root element?

Comment: logger name="" does nothing, the rootlogger does what you think name="" does.

Comment: @guido: if I put a ref to fileB in root, then all other loggers will only write to it on WARN and above, where I want them to write to it on DEBUG and above

Comment: @oers: that's what I was thinking.  Is there a way to emulate rootlogger so I can use it in the ancestry chain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need:

```
<logger name="my.app" additivity="false">
    <level="DEBUG"/>
    <appender-ref ref="console"/>
    <appender-ref ref="file"/>
</logger>

<root>
    <appender-ref ref="console-warn"/>
    <appender-ref ref="file-debug"/>
</root>
```

For the root-appender you need two new console/file appenders, that have the desired level restrictions.

```
<appender name="file-debug" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender">
    <param name="Threshold" value="DEBUG"/>
</appender>

<appender name="console-warn" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
    <param name="Threshold" value="WARN"/>
</appender>
```

Comment: I apologize, but I had a typo in the original post.  Both are actually file appenders.  Is it possible to have two different file appenders write to the same file?

Comment: @Josh I don't think so: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4046825/log4j-have-multiple-appenders-write-to-the-same-file-with-one-that-always-logs

Comment: Hm thanks.  But you are right, your solution would work for my original problem of console and file.