# Is it safe to use the same log file by two different appenders

Tags: java, log4j

```
log4j.rootLogger=error,network
log4j.appender.defaultLog=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.defaultLog.DatePattern=${roll.pattern.daily}
log4j.appender.defaultLog.file=/var/log/tomcat7/hello.log
log4j.appender.defaultLog.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.defaultLog.layout.ConversionPattern=${log.format}

log4j.logger.timing=info, timing
log4j.appender.timing=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.timing.DatePattern=${roll.pattern.daily}
log4j.appender.timing.file=/var/log/tomcat7/hello.log
log4j.appender.timing.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.timing.layout.ConversionPattern=${log.format}
```

What I want to achieve is log **network** in level ERROR and **timing** in level INFO. Can I do what I have described up there?. Or will it cause any problem two processors trying to access the same file. Is there any simpler way of specifying this other that defining two diferent appenders.

Comment: A similar question here -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4046825/log4j-have-multiple-appenders-write-to-the-same-file-with-one-that-always-logs ; Also, why use the root logger?

Comment: I found that. But I cant change the Java code now. I need to make this happen by only changing log properties